# walking and averaging values in python

Tags: python

i have to process `.txt` files presnent in  subfolder inside a Folder.like:
`New Folder>Folder 1 to 6>xx.txt & yy.txt(files present in each folder)`
each file contain two columns as:

```
arg  his
asp  gln
glu  his
```

and

```
arg his
glu arg
arg his
glu asp
```

now what I have to do is :
1)count number of occurance of each word for each file > and average total count by dividing with `total no. of lines in that file`
2)then with values obtained after completing 1st step, divide the values with total no. of files present in the folder for averaging (i.e. 2 in this case)
I have tried with my code as follows:
but I have succeeded in 1st case but I'm not getting 2nd case.

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    aspCount = 0
    glu_count = 0
    lys_count = 0
    arg_count = 0
    his_count = 0
    acid_count = 0
    base_count = 0
    count = 0
    listOfFile = glob.iglob(os.path.join(root,'*.txt')
    for filename in listOfFile:
        lineCount = 0
        asp_count_col1 = 0
        asp_count_col2 = 0
        glu_count_col1 = 0
        glu_count_col2 = 0
        lys_count_col1 = 0
        lys_count_col2 = 0
        arg_count_col1 = 0
        arg_count_col2 = 0
        his_count_col1 = 0
        his_count_col2 = 0
        count += 1
        for line in map(str.split,inp):
            saltCount += 1
            k = line[4]
            m = line[6]
            if k == 'ASP':
               asp_count_col1 += 1
            elif m == 'ASP':
               asp_count_col2 += 1
            if k == 'GLU':
               glu_count_col += 1
            elif m == 'GLU':
                glu_count_col2 += 1
            if k == 'LYS':
                lys_count_col1 += 1
            elif m == 'LYS':
                lys_count_col2 += 1
            if k == 'ARG':
                arg_count_col1 += 1
            elif m == 'ARG':
                arg_count_col2 += 1
            if k == 'HIS':
                his_count_col1 += 1
            elif m == 'HIS':
                his_count_col2 += 1
        asp_count = (float(asp_count_col1 + asp_count_col2))/lineCount   
        glu_count = (float(glu_count_col1 + glu_count_col2))/lineCount   
        lys_count = (float(lys_count_col1 + lys_count_col2))/lineCount   
        arg_count = (float(arg_count_col1 + arg_count_col2))/lineCount   
        his_count = (float(his_count_col1 + his_count_col2))/lineCount
```

upto this I could be able to get the average value per file. But how could I be able to get average per subfolder(i.e. by dividing with count(total no. of file)).
the problem is 2nd part. 1st part is done. The code provided will average values for each file. But I want to add this averages and make a new average by dividing with total no. of files present in the sub-folder.

Comment: When defining a specification, it helps to be extremely precise, or very redundant. For example "avarege per subfolder" could mean many things. And step #1 could have used an example (e.g. `arg arg \n his arg` would result in `{'arg':3/2, 'his':1/2}`) and be called "average aminoacid per pair". It would also help to give context as to why they are paired: presumably it's two strands of DNA?

Comment: @ninjagecko but this is not my concern.I just want to concentrate on numerical not in 'paired' or amino acid things.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. Is it how to count files in a subfolder?

Comment: @Ovisek: specification is your concern. You cannot expect people to help you if they don't know what you're trying to do. For example, Janne Karila just asked you the same thing. (not necessarily amino acids, more like what you mean by "average per subfolder"; subfolders imply you have a folder hierarchy; what is the hierarchy; what do you want to do with those folders)

Comment: I told the hierarchy before...It's like: New Folder>folder 1 to 4> xx.txt & yy.txt(files present in each folder).  this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `os.walk` together with `glob.iglob` is bogus. Either use one or the other, not both together. Here's how I would do it:

```
import os, os.path, re, pprint, sys
#...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  counts = {}
  nlines = 0
  for f in filter(lambda n: re.search(r'\.txt$', n), files):
    for l in open(f, 'rt'):
      nlines += 1
      for k in l.split():
        counts[k] = counts[k]+1 if k in counts else 1
  for k, v in counts.items():
    counts[k] = float(v)/nlines

  sys.stdout.write('Frequencies for directory %s:\n'%root
  pprint.pprint(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from collections import *

aminoAcids = set('asp glu lys arg his'.split())

filesToCounts = {}

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(subfolderPath):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            path = os.path.join(root,file)
            with open(path) as f:
                acidsInFile = f.read().split()

            assert all(a in aminoAcids for a in acidsInFile)
            filesToCounts[file] = Counter(acidsInFile)

def averageOfCounts(counts):
    numberOfAcids = sum(counts.values())
    assert numberOfAcids%2==0
    numberOfAcidPairs = numberOfAcids/2
    return dict((acid,acidCount/numberOfAcidPairs) for acid,acidCount in counts.items())

filesToAverages = dict((file,averageOfCounts(counts)) for file,counts in filesToCounts.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ninjagecko's answer but understand the question differently. Using his code as starting point I propose this:

```
import os
from collections import *

aminoAcids = set('asp glu lys arg his'.split())

subfolderFreqs = {}

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(subfolderPath):
    cumulativeFreqs = defaultdict(int)
    fileCount = 0
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fileCount += 1
            path = os.path.join(root,file)
            with open(path) as f:
                acidsInFile = f.read().split()

            counts = Counter(acidsInFile)
            assert aminoAcids.issuperset(counts)
            numberOfAcidPairs = len(acidsInFile)/2
            for acid, acidCount in counts.items():
                cumulativeFreqs[acid] += float(acidCount) / numberOfAcidPairs
    if fileCount:
        subfolderFreqs[root] = {acid: cumulative/fileCount for acid, cumulative in cumulativeFreqs.items()}

print subfolderFreqs
```